# Can I have more than one beloved?

Tags: meaning

Certainly, I can have many relationships that I describe as beloved (adj).

"These are my beloved children."

But, according to common understanding, can I have more than one beloved (noun)? 
If I refer to someone as "My beloved," does that imply to to listener that I am speaking of my romantic one-and-only?

(Note:  I am not asking a philosophical question about monogamy.  Only about common interpretation of a word ;)

ADDITION (based on comments/answers):  Can anyone find a reputable example of the plural "beloveds" used in a context that implies more than one beloved per person?

Comment: No, I would not interpret it that way.  And isn't this something one can find in a dictionary?

Comment: @GEdgar I looked in several dictionaries.  They were not explicit.  I asked because this is how I personally would interpret it.  It is how my roommate would interpret it.  I have never heard it in any other context, nor have I ever seen or heard it in the plural.

Comment: It's definitely singular for "beloved wife" if you value your marriage!

Comment: @RandolfRichardson: It has been clearly stated that this is not a philosophical question, so why would you even start with that? Furthermore, your comment is off-topic, because the question is not about the adjective, but about the noun.

Comment: At a marriage ceremony, the officiant begins by addressing the entire congregation as "Dearly beloved".  Or have I misinterpreted that?

Comment: @GEdgar:  adjective form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plural of *beloved* is [*beloveds*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beloveds), therefore you would say:

> My beloveds.

By that note, *my beloved* can only be understood as one beloved, one person. Unless that listener's English is poor, that is.

For a further example, there's a book called [*Lovers and Beloveds*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0807130516).

Also, what about [*Dante's Two Beloveds*](http://www.allbookstores.com/Dantes-Two-Beloveds-Ethics-Erotics/9780300125429)?

> Re-examining key passages in Dante’s oeuvre in the light of the crucial issue of moral choice, this book provides a new thematic framework for interpreting the Divine Comedy. Olivia Holmes shows how Dante articulated the relationship between the human and the divine as **an erotic choice between two attractive women — Beatrice and the “other woman.”** Investigating the traditions and archetypes that **contributed to the formation of Dante’s two beloveds**, Holmes shows how Dante brilliantly overlaid and combined these paradigms in his poem.

Comment: Shouldn't "beloved" be the standard English plural of "beloved"? Emma Lazarus didn't write "Give me your tireds, your poors ...". This would explain why "beloveds" is so rare.

Comment: @PeterShor Perhaps NY's unemployeds can be put to work carving the S's in.

Comment: I think OP is simply conflating usage of *beloved* with *betrothed, spouse, etc.* - words which in most cultures invariably identfy a single individual. As a noun, *beloved* may be used that way, but it can also be used the same as *flatmate, penpal, etc.* where there's no necessary implication of only one person occupying that role.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an often mentioned quote by political humorist and writer Molly Ivins: "The thing about democracy, beloveds, is that it is not neat, orderly, or quiet. It requires a certain relish for confusion."